# Contiguous memory allocation using first-fit algorithm

Tags: python, memory-management

This project I'm dealing with will read the size of free memory segments and size of processes from a text file and then will try to allocate a memory partition for each process using the first-fit, best-fit and worst-fit allocation algorithms. Below is the first part of the code I wrote.

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename, "r") as file:
        free_memory = file.readline().strip().split(',')
        process_size = list(map(int, file.readline().strip().split(',')))       

file = open("output.txt","w")



#---------------------------#
#First-Fit Memory Allocation#
#---------------------------#

file.write(f"First-Fit Memory Allocation\n{'-'*60}\n") 
file.write(f"start => {' '.join(free_memory)}\n")

memory = list(map(int, free_memory)) 
memory_str = list(free_memory)

for process in process_size:
        data = f"{process} => "
        allocated = False
        for index in range(len(memory)):
                if not allocated and memory[index] >= process:
                        memory[index] -= process
                        memory_str[index] = memory_str[index][:-1*len(str(process))]
                        memory_str[index] += f"{process}*" 

                        if(memory[index] != 0):
                                memory_str[index] += f" {memory[index]}"
                        allocated = True
                
                data += f"{memory_str[index]} " 

        if(not allocated):
                data = f"{process} => not allocated, must wait"              

        file.write(data+'\n')
```

Comment: Please show an example input file.

Comment: There appears to be [this duplicate question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/261590/120114) - does the input there suffice as the input here?

Answer (score 1):

I think from a prior question the input is:

```
300,600,350,200,750,125
115,500,358,200,375
```

I believe the assignment asked for a simplification of the code as it is a little convoluted at the moment. I'll try to clean it up a bit.

I've added what I guess are the other additional "strategies" as well.

I think the major difference between the given code and what I am going to offer is that the original maintains a string and integer version of the memory regions for what looks like the purpose of flagging a region as "in use" with a `*`. I'm going to use a tuple to indicate the `(size, availability)` of the memory block. then when printing we can look to add the flag as appropriate.

At the moment, our strategy is set to "First Fit":

```
## ---------------------------
## We print a nice display of memory in a few places so let's make a method to do that
## ---------------------------
def format_memory(memory_blocks):
    return ' '.join(str(x[0]) + ("" if x[1] else "*") for x in memory_blocks)
## ---------------------------

## ---------------------------
## Pick one of these to be your fit_strategy.
## ---------------------------
def get_fit_strategy(key):
    def find_candidates(memory_blocks, process_size):
        return [(idx, val) for (idx, val) in enumerate(memory_blocks) if val[1] and val[0] >= process_size]

    def first_fit(memory_blocks, process_size):
        candidates = find_candidates(memory_blocks, process_size)
        return next((candidate[0] for candidate in candidates), None)

    def best_fit(memory_blocks, process_size):
        candidates = find_candidates(memory_blocks, process_size)
        candidates = sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1][0])
        return next((candidate[0] for candidate in candidates), None)

    def worst_fit(memory_blocks, process_size):
        candidates = find_candidates(memory_blocks, process_size)
        candidates = sorted(candidates, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1][0])
        return next((candidate[0] for candidate in candidates), None)
    
    ## ---------------------------
    ## keep the name and the implementation aligned.
    ## ---------------------------
    strategies = {
        "first" : {"nm": "First Fit", "fn": first_fit},
        "best" : {"nm": "Best Fit", "fn": best_fit},
        "worst" : {"nm": "Worst Fit", "fn": worst_fit}
    }
    ## ---------------------------

    ## ---------------------------
    ## get a strategy falling back to "first"
    ## ---------------------------
    selected_strategy = strategies.get(key, strategies["first"])
    ## ---------------------------

    ## ---------------------------
    ## when called, return the name and implementation of our strategy
    ## ---------------------------
    return (selected_strategy["nm"], selected_strategy["fn"])
    ## ---------------------------

fit_strategy_name, get_free_block_index = get_fit_strategy("first")
## ---------------------------

## ---------------------------
## Read our two lines of input.
## ---------------------------
with open("memory.txt", "r") as input_file:
    ## list of tuples(size, is_available)
    memory_blocks = [(int(x), True) for x in input_file.readline().split(',')]

    ## list of process requirements
    process_sizes = [int(x) for x in input_file.readline().split(',')]
## ---------------------------

## ---------------------------
## Append each "line" to print to a list of lines to be printed at the end
## ---------------------------
results = []
results.append(f"{ fit_strategy_name } Memory Allocation")
results.append(f"{ '-' * 60 }")
results.append(f"start => { format_memory(memory_blocks) }")
## ---------------------------

## ---------------------------
## For each process (an entry in process_sizes) attempt to find a block of memory
## ---------------------------
for process_size in process_sizes:

    ## ---------------------------
    ## Using our selected strategy find the index (or None) of a block that is
    ## "free" and "big enough"
    ## ---------------------------
    index = get_free_block_index(memory_blocks, process_size)
    ## ---------------------------

    ## ---------------------------
    ## There was no appropriate block found to host this process
    ## ---------------------------
    if index is None:
        results.append(f"{ process_size } => not allocated, must wait")
        continue
    ## ---------------------------

    ## ---------------------------
    ## Insert a new memory block representing what will be the remaining memory after we
    ## allocate process_size memory out of memory_blocks[index] flagging it as available
    ## ---------------------------
    remaining_allocation = memory_blocks[index][0] - process_size
    if remaining_allocation:
        memory_blocks.insert(index+1, (remaining_allocation, True))
    ## ---------------------------

    ## ---------------------------
    ## Allocate our memory flagging it as unavailable (False)
    ## ---------------------------
    memory_blocks[index] = (process_size, False)
    ## ---------------------------

    results.append(f"{ process_size } => { format_memory(memory_blocks) }")
## ---------------------------

## ---------------------------
## now write the results that we stored in the list
## ---------------------------
with open("output.txt","w") as output_file:
    output_file.write('\n'.join(results))
## ---------------------------
```

When run it will produce a file (`output.txt`) with the following contents:

```
First Fit Memory Allocation
------------------------------------------------------------
start => 300 600 350 200 750 125
115 => 115* 185 600 350 200 750 125
500 => 115* 185 500* 100 350 200 750 125
358 => 115* 185 500* 100 350 200 358* 392 125
200 => 115* 185 500* 100 200* 150 200 358* 392 125
375 => 115* 185 500* 100 200* 150 200 358* 375* 17 125
```