# Fit memory allocation

Tags: python, memory-management

The program will read size of free memory partitions and size of processes from a text file and then will try to allocate a memory partition for each process using the first-fit algorithm.

Input example:

```
300,600,350,200,750,125
115,500,358,200,375
```

My code for the implementation:

```
import sys
 
filename = sys.argv[1]
 
with open(filename, "r") as file:
        free_memory = file.readline().strip().split(',')
        process_size = list(map(int, file.readline().strip().split(',')))       
 
file = open("output.txt","w")
 
 
#---------------------------#
#First-Fit Memory Allocation#
#---------------------------#
 
file.write(f"First-Fit Memory Allocation\n{'-'*60}\n")
file.write(f"start => {' '.join(free_memory)}\n")
 
memory = list(map(int, free_memory))
memory_str = list(free_memory)
for process in process_size:
        data = f"{process} => "
        allocated = False
        for index in range(len(memory)):
                if not allocated and memory[index] >= process:
                        memory[index] -= process
                        memory_str[index] = memory_str[index][:-1*len(str(process))]
                        memory_str[index] += f"{process}*" 
 
                        if(memory[index] != 0):
                                memory_str[index] += f" {memory[index]}"
                        allocated = True
                
                data += f"{memory_str[index]} " 
 
        if(not allocated):
                data = f"{process} => not allocated, must wait"              
 
        file.write(data+'\n')
```

My code works so far but I want to reformat my code to make it simpler and more readable. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. What Python version did you write this for?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/261581/contiguous-memory-allocation-using-first-fit-algorithm . Are you the same user, is this in the same class, or what?